# Append JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object array of the structure coming from server response like as sample

```
array1 ={
    "ID": "123",
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "15"     
}
array2 ={
    "ID": "456",
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Age": "18"     
}
```

But now I want to append the both the array values in the following structure of

Expected Output:

```
{
    "Stud": [{
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "15"
    }, {
        "ID": "456",
        "Name": "Sue",
        "Age": "18"
    }]
}
```

Can anyone help to solve in the JavaScript language. Thanks for the Time to spend for request.

Comment: `var obj = {  Stud: [array1, array2] }` - btw `array1` and `array2` are objects, not arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array1 ={
    "ID": "123",
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": "15"     
}
var array2 ={
    "ID": "456",
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Age": "18"     
}

var Output = {
  "Stud": [array1, array2]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

array1 & array 2 are litteral objects not array ;)

You can solve your problem with

```js
const array1 ={
     "ID": "123",
     "Name": "John",
     "Age": "15"     
};
const array2 ={
    "ID": "456",
    "Name": "Sue",
    "Age": "18"     
};

const stud = {
  Stud : [array1, array2]
};
```

If you have N array you can use [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj1 ={
 "ID": "123",
 "Name": "John",
 "Age": "15"     
}
var obj2 ={
 "ID": "456",
 "Name": "Sue",
 "Age": "18"     
}

var obj3 = {
  "Stud": [obj1, obj2]
}

var objJSon = JSON.stringify(obj3);
```

To get the result as JSON